# use value from tag with CDATA in CHOOSE/IF statement XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to change the value from one XML to another
if it reads monthly it should change it to 1.
This is the original XML:

```
<ser:getArtifactContentResponse    xmlns:ser="http://services.generic.governance.carbon.wso2.org" xmlns:ns3="http://test.com/test/jibxbeans">
    <ns3:frequency>
        <![CDATA[ Monthly ]]>
    </ns3:frequency>
</ser:getArtifactContentResponse>
```

This is the XSLT that I am trying:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns3="http://test.com/test/jibxbeans" xmlns:ser="http://services.generic.governance.carbon.wso2.org"
    version="1.0" xmlns:ns="http://services.generic.governance.carbon.wso2.org">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:if test="/ser:getArtifactContentResponse/ns3:frequency= ' Monthly ' ">
            <ns3:frequency>1</ns3:frequency>
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNEj9dw

expected output is

```
<ns3:frequency>1</ns3:frequency>
```

Comment: While asking a question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tried to implement it.
(3) Desired output.
(4) XSLT processor and its compliance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test fails because the `ns3:frequency` element contains more white space than you're testing for. Try:

```
<xsl:if test="normalize-space(/ser:getArtifactContentResponse/ns3:frequency) = 'Monthly'">
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried contain instead and it works

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns3="http://test.com/test/jibxbeans" xmlns:ser="http://services.generic.governance.carbon.wso2.org"
    version="1.0" xmlns:ns="http://services.generic.governance.carbon.wso2.org">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:if test="contains(/ser:getArtifactContentResponse/ns3:frequency/text(),'Monthly')">
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;ns3:frequency>1&lt;/ns3:frequency></xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: There should NEVER be a need to create markup by disabling the escaping of output text. Note that your result is not a wel-formed XML document: you cannot use a prefix without binding it to namespace.

Comment: BTW, I did not suggest using `contains()` because you did not say what other values are possible. For example, your test would return true for a value of `"Bi-Monthly"`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k what do you mean by prefix? I picked up XSLT today...

Comment: In your example, `ns3` is a prefix. Read up on namespaces.